# Racket Function Calls Count

Tags: sorting, scheme, racket, function-calls

Hey all,

So in my never-ending quest to learn more Racket, I'm trying to understand set! calls and how it can be used as a counter for counting function calls.

I coded some basic sorting algorithms (merge, insertion, quick) that are dependent on a comparison operator (i.e: <, >, <=), and I want to know how many times the operator is called to try and figure out its efficiency.  The code format I'm working with is:

```
(count-compares sort compare? lst)
```

where sort is the sorting method I coded, compare? is the comparison operator, and lst is the list of integers to be sorted.  I'm open to changing the format if you think there's a better approach.

I know compare? needs to be broken off (using another function??) to include a set!, but I'm not sure how to do that.  Does anyone have any suggestions on where to start?

Thanks! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it directly and without any package!

Define outside off all methods a var:
(define count-comp 0)

to your compare-function add the statement
(set! count-comp (+ count-comp 1))

Later use 
(display count-comp)
(set! count-comp 0)

Answer (score 1):

The [*mock*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/mock/index.html) package makes counting calls of functions like `compare?` much easier. It provides the [`mock-num-calls`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/mock/mock-reference.html?#(def._((lib._mock%2Fmain..rkt)._mock-num-calls))) function to count the number of times a mock function has been called.

```
#lang racket

(require mock)

;; count-compares :
;; ∀[X] [(Listof X) [X X -> Bool] -> (Listof X)] [X X -> Bool] (Listof X) -> Nat
(define (count-compares sort compare? lst)
  ; mock-compare? is a function that behaves just like compare?, except that
  ; it keeps track of the information of how it's called, so that it can be
  ; counted later.
  (define mock-compare? (mock #:behavior compare?))
  ; sort the list using the mock function
  (sort lst mock-compare?)
  ; count the number of times the mock function was called
  (mock-num-calls mock-compare?))
```

Trying it out:

```
(count-compares sort < '(6 2 8 3 1 8 5 3 0 7 1 7 9 5 8))
; 41, in Racket version 6.11
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I didn't even know mock was a thing!  It's very helpful :)